# MEAD (Perl Package) Installation

Tags: perl, summarization

I am trying to install MEAD http://www.summarization.com/mead/ for text summarization, but when I try to run a basic example from the bin folder

```
  ./mead.pl GA3
```

I get the error below:

```
  Cannot locate loadable object for module XML::Parser::Expat in @INC (@INC contains: mead/bin/../lib mead/bin/../lib/arch /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at mead/bin/../lib/XML/Parser.pm line 15

  Compilation failed in require at mead/bin/../lib/XML/Parser.pm line 15.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at mead/bin/../lib/XML/Parser.pm line 19.
  Compilation failed in require at /mead/bin/../lib/MEAD/Cluster.pm line 16.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at mead/bin/../lib/MEAD/Cluster.pm line 16.
  Compilation failed in require at ./mead.pl line 29.
  BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./mead.pl line 29.
```

Strange enough, I already have expat installed. I am wondering, what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: It might be using the wrong Perl. Do you have several installed with perlbrew or plenv?

Comment: @simbabque No, the only version of perl that I have installed is v5.10.1

Comment: At paragraph 2.3.3 of http://www.summarization.com/mead/documentation/meaddoc.pdf I read: "Before running the installation script, you may want to check if you have the four required modules installed and install them in the normal Perl manner. If you don’t have a Perl module installed, MEAD’s install script will automatically install a copy that only it can use, so if you plan on doing XML-related work in Perl, it may well be worth your while to install these modules yourself before installing MEAD."

Comment: "Note that if at some later time, you install any of the four required modules, pre-existing versions on MEAD will not use them. You must re-install MEAD if you really want it to use your newly installed modules." So maybe it's some weird conflict between different versions of modules?

Comment: There are (at least) two different pieces of software involved here. expat is a C library for parsing XML. XML::Parser::Expat is a Perl module which is a wrapper around expat. XML::Parser::Expat is part of the XML::Parser distribution. You'll need to ensure that is installed as well.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you reading [mead documentation](https://summarization.com/mead/documentation/meaddoc.pdf) before starting. In page 7 of this document, it is pointed out the required perl libraries for mead. You can find required perl library under **path/mead/external**. Install all libraries under the external directory, it will run without any problems.

Required Libraries:

1. Perl 5.5 or above
2. XML::Parser
3. Expat
4. XML::Writer
5. XML::TreeBuilder
6. Text::Iconv
7. etc.